# C# WinForms ComboBox SelectedValue null

Tags: c#, winforms

Когда закрываю форму легко получаю значение SalectedValue ComboBox
но перед ShowDialog формы если ставлю SelectedValue для ComboBox, то ComboBox не ставит его. ComboBox внутри TableLayoutPanel вместе с Label. те set SalectedValue не работает и Items = 0, но DataSource в конструкторе установлен

```
form.EnabledLabeledCheckComboxBox.CheckComboBox.SelectedValue = true;
form.ShowDialog();
MessageBox.Show(form.EnabledLabeledCheckComboxBox.CheckComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()); // здесь то что я выберу

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class BoolKeyStringValue : BaseVM {

  #region Key
  private bool key;
  public bool Key {
    get => this.key;
    set { 
      this.key = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Key");
    } 
  }
  #endregion

  #region Value
  private string value;
  public string Value {
    get => this.value;
    set { 
      this.value = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Value");
    }
  }
  #endregion

  public BoolKeyStringValue(bool key, string value) {
    this.Key = key;
    this.Value = value;
  }
 }

 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test {
  public class LabeledCheckComboBox : TableLayoutPanel {

  #region Properties

  #region Label
  private Label label;

  public Label Label {
    get => this.label;
    set => this.label = value;
  }
  #endregion

  #region CheckComboBox
  private ComboBox checkComboBox;
  public ComboBox CheckComboBox {
    get => this.checkComboBox;
    set => this.checkComboBox = value;
  }
  #endregion

  #region Bools
  private List<BoolKeyStringValue> bools;
  public List<BoolKeyStringValue> Bools {
    get => this.bools;
    set => this.bools = value;
  }
  #endregion

  #endregion

  #region Constructors
  public LabeledCheckComboBox() {

  #region Label
  this.Label = new Label();
  this.Label.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
  this.Label.Margin = new Padding(0);
  #endregion

  #region Bools
  this.Bools = new List<BoolKeyStringValue>();
  this.Bools.Add(new BoolKeyStringValue(false, "No"));
  this.Bools.Add(new BoolKeyStringValue(true, "Yes"));
  #endregion

  #region Init
  this.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
  this.Margin = new Padding(0, 1, 0, 0);
  this.RowCount = 2;
  this.ColumnCount = 1;
  this.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
  this.Controls.Add(this.Label, 0, 0);

  this.CheckComboBox = new ComboBox();
  this.CheckComboBox.Items.AddRange(this.Bools.ToArray());
  this.CheckComboBox.DataSource = this.Bools;
  this.CheckComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
  this.CheckComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
  this.CheckComboBox.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
  this.CheckComboBox.Margin = new Padding(3, 0, 0, 0);
  this.CheckComboBox.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
  this.CheckComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
  this.CheckComboBox.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
  this.Controls.Add(this.CheckComboBox, 0, 1);

  #endregion
  }
  #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, класс `BaseVM` реализует интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov он никак не изменяется, я засетил Items ему а не DataSource и все)

Answer (score 2):

Читайте документацию (можно прямо в Студии навести мышку на свойство и всплывет подсказка с описанием).

[SelectedValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_SelectedValue) property:

> Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the **ValueMember** property.

Выделил важное.

Вам, вероятно, следует использовать [SelectedItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ComboBox_SelectedItem):

> Gets or sets currently selected item in the ComboBox.

Comment: у меня указан ValueMember, и я получаю null, сейчас добавлю код

Comment: @MikeWaters вы похоже не улавливаете разницы между `SelectedItem` и `SelectedValue`. Вы когда делаете так `SelectedValue = true`, то вы должны сначала удостовериться, что у вас `SelectedItem != null`, иначе ваше присваивание улетает в пустоту.

Comment: @Bulson у меня SelectedItem == null, почему?

Comment: @MikeWaters очевидно, потому, что нет выбранного элемента в комбобоксе

Comment: @Bulson я ему скормил DataSource, елементы есть

Comment: @Bulson а Items пусто

Comment: @MikeWaters элементы, это просто коллекция. А есть выбранный программно или пользователем элемент из этой коллекции

Comment: @Bulson и в чем проблема?) я не понимаю)

Comment: Добавил полный код класса

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой класс будет элементом в коллекции комбобокса

```
public class ComboBoxElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Вот пример на поиграться. Кстати если напрямую, как вы это делаете назначать SelectedValue значение, то выбранный элемент становится равным `null`.

```
public partial class MainView : Form
{
    private BindingSource _bsCombobox = new BindingSource();

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetBindings();

        GetData();
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        _bsCombobox.DataSource = typeof(List<ComboBoxElement>);
        _comboBoxAnimals.DataSource = _bsCombobox;
        _comboBoxAnimals.DisplayMember = "Name";
        _comboBoxAnimals.ValueMember = "Id";
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        _bsCombobox.DataSource = new List<ComboBoxElement>
        {
            new ComboBoxElement { Id = 1, Name = "Кошка" },
            new ComboBoxElement { Id = 2, Name = "Собака" },
            new ComboBoxElement { Id = 3, Name = "Корова" },
        };
    }

    private void _buttonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show((_bsCombobox.Current as ComboBoxElement).Name);
        //или так
        MessageBox.Show((_comboBoxAnimals.SelectedItem as ComboBoxElement).Name);
    }

    private void _buttonSelectCow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //_comboBoxAnimals.SelectedIndex = _comboBoxAnimals.FindString("Корова");

        //или так
        var element = _bsCombobox.OfType<ComboBoxElement>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.Name.Equals("Корова"));
        _bsCombobox.Position = _bsCombobox.IndexOf(element);
    }

    private void _buttonSelectDog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////выбираем собаку
        //_comboBoxAnimals.SelectedIndex = _comboBoxAnimals.FindString("Собака");

        ////изменяем у нее Id, который у нас назначен как ValueMember и сначала =2
        //_comboBoxAnimals.SelectedValue = 1000; //!!! это действие делает SelectedItem = null
        ////и здесь вылетает ошибка, хотя по-идее должно бы быть окошко с 1000
        //MessageBox.Show(_comboBoxAnimals.SelectedValue.ToString());

        //потому лучше так
        var element = _bsCombobox.OfType<ComboBoxElement>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.Name.Equals("Собака"));

        element.Id = 1000;
        _bsCombobox.Position = _bsCombobox.IndexOf(element);

        MessageBox.Show(_comboBoxAnimals.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```